# How to clear a string after class is used?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, palindrome

This is a palindrome algorithm that I'm working on.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
    
public class Palindrome {
    String reverse = "";

    Palindrome() {}


    String reverseStr(String inputs) {
        for (int i = inputs.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            reverse += inputs.charAt(i);
        }
        return reverse;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Palindrome sinput = new Palindrome();
        int choice = 1;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (choice <= 1) {

            System.out.println("Print new word");
            String inputs = scan.nextLine();

            String reversed = sinput.reverseStr(inputs);
            System.out.println(reversed);
            //   reversed.clear();   Doesn't work creates Complier error
            //  reversed.nextLine();  Doesn't work creates Complier error
            scan.reset(); // Doesn't work 
            //reversed.fill(reversed,0); Doesn't work 
            System.out.println("To Continue with new word Enter 1 ; to quit Enter One");

            String choiceString = scan.nextLine();
            choice = Integer.parseInt(choiceString);

            if (choice == 1) {
                continue;

            } else if (choice > 1) {
                break;
            }
        }

        scan.close();
    }
}
```

It works only with one exception. Instead of clearing out a string, it appends it. I tried a couple of examples. The ones that I tried are commented out. I still want to keep the palindrome class as a separate class. What would be the best way to clear reverse or `sinput` screen each time while loop runs?

Comment: Please try to have your posted code adhere to standard Java code formatting since your current code is a bit hard to read, something that doesn't help us understand it easily or you get answers easily.

Comment: I just posted edits to the formatting, way easier to read it now. I copy+pasted into IntelliJ, didn't add/remove anything else (the dangling `;` was there before, too).

Comment: @Kaan Sheesh, thanks mate, might not be the OP, but you made things a LOT easier considering the edit queue is full on my side.

Comment: Yes, thanks @Kaan. The original poster is not new, and so I am a bit surprised that they posted almost unreadable code as by now they really should know better.

Comment: This question was only for educational purposes. I know there is a more efficient way to do it.  but the purpose of this exercise is to declare class, for loop, and actually run the palindrome algorithm without importing any utility tools. The code actually works, but instead of outputting new string it appends to the old one.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by updating your `reverseStr` method by moving `reverse` into the method which will effectively have a fresh string every time you call reverseStr, otherwise you can use `reverse = "";` before the method to "reset" it. Here is a working solution:

```
String reverseStr(String inputs) {
    //Move the reverse variable inside you mothed so that it gets reset every time reverseStr is called
    String reverse=""; 

    //Now do the loop
    for (int i =inputs.length()-1; i>=0; i-- ) {
        reverse+=inputs.charAt(i);      
    }
    return reverse;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating through a string character-by-character and reinventing the wheel:

*"Why not just use what Java already has built-in?"*

Also, **you don't need a variable which complicates and gives you further problems.**

```
    String reverseStr(String inputs) {
      return new StringBuilder(inputs).reverse().toString();
    }
```

Edit:

```
    // Add the import before the class:
    import java.lang.StringBuilder;
```

Last Edit:

**This has already been tested on JShell, built in with the JDK**

```
    jshell> import java.lang.StringBuilder;

    jshell> System.out.println(new StringBuilder("Testing input").reverse().toString());

    tupni gnitseT
```